# NSTableViewDiffableDataSource allowing for Drag and Drop in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit

I seems that NSTableViewDiffableDataSource does not allow for the drag and drop delegate functions on an NSTableView like the normal data source.

I have see this thread https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/674377 that talks about how to solve this issue using Objective-c, however, I can not get this implemented with swift.  Please note that my view controllers are using Swift and not Objective-C.

How can I make NSTableViewDiffableDataSource work with the drag and drop methods using Swift?

What I have tried:

MyDiffableDataSource.h

```
@class MyDiffableDataSource;


@protocol MyDiffableDataSourceDelegate <NSObject>

- (nullable id <NSPasteboardWriting>)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
                        pasteboardWriterForRow:(NSInteger)row;

- (void)tableView: (NSTableView *)tableView
  draggingSession: (NSDraggingSession *)session
 willBeginAtPoint: (NSPoint)screenPoint
    forRowIndexes: (NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes;


- (NSDragOperation)tableView: (NSTableView *)tableView
                validateDrop: (id <NSDraggingInfo>)draggingInfo
                 proposedRow: (NSInteger)row
       proposedDropOperation: (NSTableViewDropOperation)dropOperation;



- (BOOL)tableView: (NSTableView *)tableView
       acceptDrop: (id <NSDraggingInfo>)draggingInfo
              row: (NSInteger)row
    dropOperation: (NSTableViewDropOperation)dropOperation;



- (void)tableView: (NSTableView *)tableView
  draggingSession: (NSDraggingSession *)session
     endedAtPoint: (NSPoint)screenPoint
        operation: (NSDragOperation)operation;

@end



@interface MyDiffableDataSource : NSTableViewDiffableDataSource

@property (weak, nonatomic, readwrite) id <MyDiffableDataSourceDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Also, in MyDiffableDataSource.m:

```
- (nullable id <NSPasteboardWriting>)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
                        pasteboardWriterForRow:(NSInteger)row

{

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(tableView:pasteboardWriterForRow:)]){

        return [self.delegate tableView: tableView
                 pasteboardWriterForRow: row];

    }
    return nil;
}
```

With this above code I cannot call

```
typealias TableDataSource = MyDiffableDataSource<Int, Node>
```

[image]

as MyDiffableDataSource.h should be a subclass of NSTableViewDiffableDataSource.

I have to get rid of <Int, Node> which defines the data model.

Using the MyDiffableDataSource class in Objective-C, how would I replace this code?

```
typealias TableDataSource = NSTableViewDiffableDataSource<Int, Node>
```

It seems that I cannot do `typealias TableDataSource = MyDiffableDataSource<Int,Node>`  as the MyDiffableDataSource does not allow for specific data types.

Comment: Post the code you tried please. Where are you stuck?

Comment: The linked answer says "you need to subclass NSTableViewDiffableDataSource and implement the drag and drop API in that subclass.", All `MyDiffableDataSource` does is forwarding the drag & drop methods to its delegate. Did you try this in Swift?

Comment: @Willeke thank you.  I did try that in swift, however, when trying to see if I could use an Objective-C subclass of  NSTableViewDiffableDataSource in my Swift NSTableView, but it looks like there might not be a way to set the data type similarly to the swift way.  It comes out having an Any type

```lazy var data: TableDataSource = {
        let datasource = TableDataSource(tableView: tableView) { tableView, tableColumn, row, <#Any#> in
            
        }
    }()```

Comment: I am trying to replace this code using the Obj-c subclass `typealias TableDataSource = NSTableViewDiffableDataSource<Int, Node>` but the objective c  subclass does not allow me to declare the type to be <Int, Node>